# Setting nvidia-driver to work with tensorflow 2.15 [GPU]

Tags: tensorflow, ubuntu, gpu, driver, nvidia

Everyone!

I'm trying to make tensorflow 2.15 to work with my GPU - NVIDIA GeForce GTX 750 Ti.

tensorflow docs - https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source?hl=pt-br#gpu

```
GPU - config - from tensorflow docs - https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source?hl=pt-br#gpu
Versão  Versão Python   Compilador  Ferramentas de construção   cuDNN   CUDA
tensorflow-2.15.0   3.9-3.11    Clang 16.0.0    Bazel 6.1.0 8.8 12.2
```

My OS is: Ubuntu 23.04

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 545.29.06              Driver Version: 545.29.06    CUDA Version: 12.3     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce GTX 750 Ti      Off | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 33%   37C    P8               1W /  38W |    436MiB /  4096MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      2553      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                          187MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2695      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                         26MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3356      G   ...sion,SpareRendererForSitePerProcess       53MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3743      G   ...onEnabled --variations-seed-version      129MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     42678      C   /usr/bin/python3                             27MiB |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Jul_28_19:07:16_PDT_2019
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.243

$ python --version         
Python 3.11.4

~ ⌚ 18:14:55
$ bazel --version
bazel 6.1.0

~ ⌚ 18:15:05
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~23.04) 12.3.0
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ cat /etc/os-release             
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 23.04"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="23.04"
VERSION="23.04 (Lunar Lobster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=lunar
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=lunar
LOGO=ubuntu-logo
```

Now to reproduce the error, you can do the following commands:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())

## OUTPUT:
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
```

**logout error:**

2024-02-14 17:58:40.696088: E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:9261] **Unable to register cuDNN factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuDNN when one has already been registered**
2024-02-14 17:58:40.696166: E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_fft.cc:607] **Unable to register cuFFT factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuFFT when one has already been registered**
2024-02-14 17:58:40.829634: E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:1515] **Unable to register cuBLAS factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuBLAS when one has already been registered**
2024-02-14 17:58:40.984397: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
**To enable the following instructions: AVX2 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.**
2024-02-14 17:58:43.234200: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT
2.15.0
2024-02-14 17:58:44.809184: I external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_executor.cc:901] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero. See more at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v6.0/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-bus-pci#L344-L355
2024-02-14 17:58:45.101985: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:2256] **Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU.** Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...

If someone can help me to fix this issue!
I trying to reinstall and I don't know anything else to fix this! I try a lot of thing!

Thanks!

Comment: Did you execute the steps in the _"Install GPU support (optional, Linux only)"_ section? You have to install NVIDIA GPU drivers, CUDA Toolkit, cuDNN SDK and TensorRT. Follow these steps: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu (the link is right in your error log).

Comment: You already linked in your question to the list of TF versions and compatible CUDA versions. TF 2.15 runs with CUDA 12.2 and cudnn 8.8, and you have CUDA 10.1 per nvcc. Upgrade your CUDA version, install the appropiate cudnn versions and it should run.